# Finer topology induced by a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I’d like to get some help about a corollary in General Topology (M. Manetti, ‘Topology’, corollary 3.50, 2015 edition).

> Let *d* and *e* be metrics on the same set *X*. Suppose there exist
> two positive (i.e. *>0*) real numbers *a* and *b* such that, for every
> *x* and *y* in *X*, it is true that *d(x,y) >= min {a/b, e(x,y)/b}*. Show that the topology *s* induced by *d* is at least as fine as the
> topology *t* induced by *e* (e.g. t is a subset of s, if a topology is
> stated to be the set of its open sets).

The book gives two hints:

1. Use the following proposition: give *d* and *e* metrics on the same set *X*, to show that *d* induces a topology on *X* which is at least as fine as the one induced by *e*, it is sufficient to show that for every positive real number *h* there exists a positive real number *k* such that, for every *x* and *y* in *X*, if *d(x,y)<=k*, then *e(x,y)<=h*;
2. In the proposition at point 1, given a and b as in the hypotheses of the corollary, set k to be min{a/b, h/b}.

I just can't guess, after many attempts, how this implies the thesis. Can you?

Comment: Can you give us some examples of your attempts? How did you use the hints?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The ways I've been working on it basically consist in fixing two points x and y, and considering separately the case in which a/b <e(x,y), and therefore the hypothesis says d(x,y)>=a/b, and the case in which a/b>=e(x,y), so the hypothesis says d(x,y)>=e(x,y)/b. In the second case, given h, I can choose k to be h/b and therefore I get e(x,y)<=h. But what about the first case? I'm also worried about the dependence of these h and k on the points x and y chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem itself and the hints pretty much answer your question, elaborated below.

In general, to show that a topology $\mathcal{S}$ is finer (not necessarily strictly) than another topology $\mathcal{T}$, it suffices to show that a basis for $\mathcal{T}$ is contained in $\mathcal{S}$. Here, we are concerned with two metric topologies, with natural basis consisting of the open balls $\{ B_f (x, r) \}$, where $x \in X$, $r > 0$ is a real number, and $f$ is a metric (as you should know, satisfying the conditions that $f (x, y) = f (y, x)$, $f (x, y) \ge 0$, $f (x, y) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x = y$, and $f (x, y) + f (y, z) \ge f (x, z)$ for all $x, y, z \in X$).

To show that the topology $\mathcal{S}$ induced by the metric $d$ is finer than the topology $\mathcal{T}$ induced by the metric $e$, we just need to show that for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d (x, y) < \delta \implies e (x, y) < \varepsilon$ for all $x, y \in X$. Why is this the case? Consider any basis element for $\mathcal{T}$, $E = B_e (x, r) = \{ y \in X | e (x, y) < r \}$, and an arbitrary point of it, $z \in E$. Let $s > 0$ be the "$\delta$" value guaranteed by the hypothesis for the "$\varepsilon$" value $r - e (x, z) > 0$. Consider the basis element $D = B_d (z, s) = \{ y \in X | d (z, y) < s \}$. It is easy to check that $D \subseteq E$. Any $w \in D$ satisfies $d (z, w) < s \implies e (z, w) < r - e (x, z)$ by the choice of $s$. Therefore, $e (x, w) \le e (x, z) + e (z, w) < e (x, z) + (r - e (x, z)) = r$ by the triangle inequality, so that $w \in B_e (x, r)$.

In this problem, we are given that for some real numbers $a, b > 0$, that $d (x, y) \ge {\rm min} \left\{ \frac{a}{b}, \frac{e (x, y)}{b} \right\}$ for all $x, y \in X$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. There are two cases we will consider: (1) $\varepsilon < a$, and (2) $\varepsilon \ge a$.

*Case 1*

In the first case, select $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{b}$. Consider $x, y \in X$ satisfying $d (x, y) < \delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{b}$. Since $\varepsilon < a$, then $d (x, y) < \frac{a}{b}$. Note that it must be the case that $\frac{e (x, y)}{b} < \frac{a}{b}$, since otherwise, we would have that $d (x, y) \ge {\rm min} \left\{ \frac{a}{b}, \frac{e (x, y )}{b} \right\} = \frac{a}{b}$ leads to a contradiction. Therefore, $d (x, y) \ge \frac{e (x, y)}{b} \implies e (x, y) \le b d (x, y) < b \left( \frac{\varepsilon}{b} \right) = \varepsilon$, as desired.

*Case 2*

In the second case, select $\delta = \frac{a}{b}$. Consider $x, y \in X$ satisfying $d (x, y) < \delta = \frac{a}{b}$. Just as in the previous case, the fact that $d (x, y) < \frac{a}{b}$ implies that $\frac{e (x, y)}{b} < \frac{a}{b}$. Therefore, $e (x, y) < a$, and since $a \le \varepsilon$, we conclude $e (x, y) < \varepsilon$, as desired.