# Comparing Metric Topologies

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I recently encountered a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4755335/302781) regarding metric topologies and was curious about a particular detail.

Suppose $X$ is a metrizable space with metrics $d$ and $e$, and let $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ be the respective induced topologies.

We have the following:

> If, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d (x, y) < \delta \implies e (x, y) < \varepsilon$ for every $x, y \in X$, then $\mathcal{S}$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}$.

This is not hard to show; one way is to take an arbitrary basis element $B_e (x, r) \in \mathcal{T}$; then, for any $y \in B_e (x, r)$, we have that $B_d (y, \delta) \subseteq B_e (x, r)$, where $\delta$ is the value guaranteed by hypothesis corresponding to $\varepsilon = r - e (x, y) > 0$ and applying the triangle inequality for $e$.

I am interested in whether the converse is true:

> If $\mathcal{S}$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}$, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d (x, y) < \delta \implies e (x, y) < \varepsilon$ for every $x, y \in X$.

My intuition tells me that this should be true, so I have tried to go about showing it as follows. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. If we can show that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $B_d (x, \delta) \subseteq B_e (x, \varepsilon)$ for each $x \in X$, then the statement is proved (since for any $x, y \in X$ satisfying $d (x, y) < \delta$, we have that $y \in B_d (x, \delta)$; therefore, $y \in B_e (x, \varepsilon)$; therefore, $e (x, y) < \varepsilon$).

This is basically where I am stuck. It is true that for each $x \in X$, we may find $\delta_x > 0$ such that $B_d (x, \delta_x) \subseteq B_e (x, \varepsilon)$; this is guaranteed by the hypothesis that $\mathcal{S}$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}$. It is tempting then to consider the value $\rho = \inf \{ \delta_x | x \in X \}$, where we can construct the set $\{ \delta_x | x \in X \}$ for general $X$ if we assume the axiom of choice. However, we have no guarantee that $\rho > 0$, so it will not suffice as the value for "$\delta$" in the statement.

However, I have also not been able to find a counterexample.

If the statement is not true, I am also interested about what properties can be placed on either the space $X$ or the metrics $d, e$ to make it true.

**Edit**

I realize that if the space $(X, \mathcal{S})$ is *compact*, then the statement is true. This is because given the cover $\mathcal{A} = \left\{ B_e \left( x, \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \right) | x \in X \right\}$ of $X$ (note that each element is contained in $\mathcal{S}$ by hypothesis that $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$), the Lebesgue number lemma guarantees some $\delta_\mathcal{A} > 0$ such that for each $x \in X$, $B_d \left( x, \delta_\mathcal{A} \right)$ is contained in some element $B_e \left( y, \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \right)$. Take $z \in B_d ( x, \delta_\mathcal{A} )$; then, we have that $z \in B_e \left( y, \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \right) \implies e (y, z) < \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$ so that $e (x, z) \le e (x, y) + e (y, z) < \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon + \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon = \varepsilon$ and thus $z \in B_e (x, \varepsilon)$ as desired.

But if $(X, \mathcal{S})$ is not compact, I do not know if the statement is true.

Comment: The converse shouldn't be true in general. It is too strong, it asks for a uniform conception of the necessary $\delta$. It's true if you allow $\delta$ to depend on $x$ and $y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that metric spaces can be homeomorphic but have inequivalent metrics.

The homeomorphism $(0,1)\cong(1,\infty)$, $x\mapsto1/x$ is a reasonable example of this. This induces two metrics on $(0,1)$, the usual one and the metric $\epsilon(x,y)=|x^{-1}-y^{-1}|$. The topologies are precisely the same, so $S$ is certainly finer than $T$. Let $\epsilon>0$; you conjecture there is a $\delta>0$ making $\epsilon(x,y)<\epsilon$ if $|x-y|<\delta$, among $x,y\in(0,1)$. This is precisely the statement that $x\mapsto1/x$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$, but this is false.

How do I know it's false? Abstractly that's because, if it were uniformly continuous, it would lift to a continuous map $[0,1]\to\Bbb R$. This much is obviously impossible. Concretely, try $\epsilon=1$. Consider pairs $(x,x/2)$; $\epsilon(x,x/2)$ will be $x^{-1}$ then, which is always greater than $1$. It is then certainly the case that no such $\delta$ exists.

As commented, your theorem statement is much too strong; it asks for the $\delta$ to be uniformly applicable. However, both your original theorem and your conjectured converse statement hold if $\delta$ is allowed to depend on $x$ and $y$.,

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I had not encountered the concept of "uniform continuity" before but I see that is exactly what is involved here.

Comment: @K.Jiang No worries. Since the concept of uniform continuity is new, I’ll give you this reference: your discovery about it being true when the spaces are compact follows from this: *every continuous function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous*. Proofs are available in many places on this site I think